# Transition between two UICollectionViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got a UICollectionView using a flow layout.

Initially it shows small cells, roughly 5 X 5 on the iPad screen.

What I want to do it smoothly change to a nearly full screen cell size, with a cell with a larger, slightly different layout.

```
----------------
| |---| |---|  |
| |   | |   |  |
| |---| |---|  |
|              |
| |---| |---|  |
| |   | |   |  |
| |---| |---|  |
----------------

transitions to..
----------------
| |---------|  |
| |         |  |
| |         |  |
| |         |  |
| |---------|  |
|              |
| |---------|  |
----------------
```

At the moment I use use a boolean `showLarge` which I set to YES when the user clicks (`didSelectItemAtIndexPath`)

Then I reload the data.

```
self.showLarge = YES;
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

In my `cellForItemAtIndexPath` I load the appropriate cell according to the boolean:

```
 if (!self.showLarge)
 {
     SmallCell *smallCell ..
     etc
     return smallCell;
 } else
 {
     LargeCell *smallCell ..
     etc
     return largeCell;
 }
```

However, this is an abrupt transition.

How would I smoothly animate to the new custom UICollectionViewCell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a different `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, then change the collection view's layout on the fly. That'll give you a nice animation without the need to reload anything.

Comment: Thanks, how would I do that?

Comment: Just use the `setCollectionViewLayout:animated:` selector on your collection view.